# Unable to access this.text in the html template

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add two buttons which should only show if there is some text in the input field else it should be hidden/disabled by default,but I'm getting this error.

`<div class="card card-body">`

```
`<form>`
    `<div class="form-group">`
        `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a Log ...">`
        `<input type="submit" value="Add Log" class="btn btn-light" [disabled]=!this.text>`
        `<button class="btn btn-warning" [hidden]=!this.text>Clear </button>`
    `</div>
`</form>
```

`</div>`

Error  :
            Clear 
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~

```
         src/app/components/log-form/log-form.component.ts:5:16
         templateUrl: './log-form.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       Error occurs in the template of component LogFormComponent.
```

Comment: Why are you using backtick ```'`'``` in your template?

Comment: Can you try this example and let me know whether this is your expectation?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-yp72ke

Comment: @Maniraj Murugan I think the just doesn't know how the markdown on stackoverflow works.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan  Yes, this is what exactly I'm trying to do

Comment: @Nitin, Hope you understand from the link provided what exactly needs to be done.. Use ```[(ngModel)]``` and ```name``` attribute then check for conditions to disable/enable/hide a button ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this easily by using ngModel as below:

mycomp.component.html

```
<form>
 <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" [(ngModel)]="textvalue" placeholder="Add a Log ...">
     <input type="submit" value="Add Log" class="btn btn-light" [disabled]="!textvalue">
     <button class="btn btn-warning" [hidden]="!textvalue">Clear </button>
 </div>
 {{textvalue}}//contains value of your input element.
</form>
```

mycomp.component.ts

```
export class MyComponent {
  textvalue:string;
}
```

Be sure to import FormsModule in the imports[] array of app.module.ts file in order for ngModel to work.Also name attribute of input is important or you could use formControlName.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **quotes** in your template:

```
[disabled]="!this.text"
```

Comment: If this solves the problem, you should say so and, perhaps, vote to close the question as a typo if you can. If this is only a comment, then please delete this as comments aren't allowed here in the Answer section. [answer]

Comment: I did try the same and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

1. No need for backticks inside of backticks
2. `"text"` not `this.text`

   ```
   `<form>
       <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a Log ...">
       <input type="submit" value="Add Log" class="btn btn-light" [disabled]="!text">
       <button class="btn btn-warning" [hidden]="!text">Clear </button>
       </div>
   </form>`
   ```

Comment: changed  `this.text` to `"this.text"`,still i'm getting the same error

Comment: please post all of your component code and try the edit as well.